# How to write a select query with Scala Anorm?

Tags: scala, anorm

How to get `user_name` value , using Scala Anorm? I tried:

```
 val result = SQL("SELECT user_name a FROM user WHERE user_id = {user_id}").on('user_id -> 1).executeQuery()           
 println("result ="+result)
```

And, I am getting  `result = SqlQueryResult(FlattenedManagedResource[?](...),false)` instead of this I was expecting `user_name` value in table.

How should I do to get what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a result parser; e.g

```
import anorm.SqlParser.scalar
val parser = scalar[String].single
// expect only one row (single),
// with only one column (scalar),
// of type String

val user: String = SQL("SELECT user_name a FROM user WHERE user_id = {user_id}").on('user_id -> 1).as(parser)
```

> It's recommended you have a look at the [documentation](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaAnorm)

Comment: Please have a look at the doc to see what are the column bindings. Try something. Then ask if you have an error.

Comment: It's recommended to read the documentation where many examples about that can be found